# How to show Repository History Graph in VS 2017?

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2017

I am using Git with Visual Studio 2017 (Professional at Work and Community at Home).

I visited https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/tutorial/history and saw that graph is available in Visual Studio Commit History.

Borrowed from link:
[image]

but I can see my commits like this (also borrowed from link)

[image]

How to enable it?

Comment: Which exact version do you have: the latest RTM from last week?

Comment: @VonC: Yes. I am using v15.0.26228.9

Comment: And I suppose a right click on the column headers des not show any "graph" option?

Comment: The only difference I see is one is the history of a *branch*, the other of a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pictures illustrates that:

- the local history of a branch comes with a graph
- the local history of a file does not

Comment: Got it. That's what I was missing. Works for me.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal That seems to be a *partial* implementation of https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/5621120-add-option-to-show-graph-in-commits-view-of-team-f

Comment: Exactly. This can lead to confusion like mine which forced me to raise this question.